# Union of a set with empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A = \{1,1,2\}$
what is its union with the empty set?

I am confused as A has a duplicate element so is the union $\{1,2\}$ or $\{1,1,2\}.$

Comment: Sets arent allowed to have duplicate elements; the set {1, 1, 2} is equivalent to {1, 2} because they contain exactly the same distinct elements.    And the union of any set with the empty set is itself, since the empty set adds no new elements

Comment: $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,1,2\}$ are both the same set, if $\{1,1,2\}$ is defined as a set at all. Sets do not have duplicate elements. There is a notion of multi-sets, but then $\{1,1,2\}\cup\emptyset = \{1,1,2\}.$ Nut multi-sets are not sets.

Comment: So if it said A={1,1,2} would you then assume that it is a multiset?

Comment: As usually we write $A = \{x, y, z\}$ and assume it is a set with potentially just one or two elements if $x, y, z$ coincide, it's natural to define $\{1, 1, 2\}$ to be the same set as $\{1, 2\}$.

Comment: If it were a multiset, I would expect to see something like $A=\{2\bullet 1, 1\bullet2\}$

Comment: Depends on the context. In elementary set theory, I would assume it is a set. Multi-sets are something completely different. @Anteater23

Comment: @Anteater23.If ever you consider my answer as helpful, you may accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The fact that the set {1,1,2} has a "duplicate element" is not a problem at all.**

Indeed the **axiom of extensionnality** tells you that

if two sets have exactly the same elements, then they are equal ( that is, they are exactly the same set) , and reciprocally.

So can you see an element of {1,2} that is not also an element of {1,1,2} ? And can you see an element of {1,1,2} that is not also an element of {1,2} ?

If you answered " no" to both questions, you know that

```
    **{1,1,2} and {1,2} are exactly the same set**, in other words, that : 

             {1,1,2} =  {1,2} , or, if you prefer {1,2} = {1,1,2}
```

Since {1,1,2} =  {1,2}, the set :  {1,1,2} U Empty set is the same set as :

```
                     **{1,2} U Empty set.**
```

And , in virtue of the definition of " union" ( symbol : U)

**{1,2} U Empty set** = the set of all x such that x belongs to {1,2} **OR** x belongs to the Empty set.

But the sentence " x belongs to the Empty set" is a contradiction.

And logic tells you that , for all proposition P :

```
          **"P OR Contradiction" is equivalent to P.**
```

( In case P is true, since the OR operator only requires that 1 at least of the 2 sentences be true to give a true statement, " P OR contradiction" is true. And if P is false, the condition for a true OR-statement is not fullfilled; so "P OR Contradiction" becomes false. You see that "P" and "P OR Contradiction" always have the same truth value, they are equivalent).

With this in mind, you can **simplify the definition of your set {1,2} U Empty** set and say that

```
        {1,2} U Empty set = the set of all x such that x belongs  {1,2}.
```

But "the set of all x such that x belongs  {1,2}" is simply the set {1,2} itself!

**Conclusion  {1,1,2} U empty set  = {1,2} U Empty set = {1,2}.**